# Nodejs: Messenger shows Bad Data Error when sending request for Broadcast Message

Tags: node.js, facebook, axios, broadcast, messenger

I am currently trying to automate the process of sending a broadcast message to Facebook so that I can trigger it from an API call.

The Http Request to my API is received and processed, but when the process begins to send the message to the **message_creatives** endpoint, it returns the following error:

```
{ Error: Request failed with status code 400
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705782+00:00 app[web.1]: at createError (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705784+00:00 app[web.1]: at settle (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:18:12)
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705787+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (/app/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/http.js:191:11)
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705789+00:00 app[web.1]: at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:164:20)
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705792+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1062:12)
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705794+00:00 app[web.1]: at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705796+00:00 app[web.1]: config:
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705798+00:00 app[web.1]: { adapter: [Function: httpAdapter],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705800+00:00 app[web.1]: transformRequest: { '0': [Function: transformRequest] },
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705801+00:00 app[web.1]: transformResponse: { '0': [Function: transformResponse] },
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705804+00:00 app[web.1]: timeout: 0,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705806+00:00 app[web.1]: xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705807+00:00 app[web.1]: xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705809+00:00 app[web.1]: maxContentLength: -1,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705810+00:00 app[web.1]: validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705812+00:00 app[web.1]: headers:
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705814+00:00 app[web.1]: { Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705815+00:00 app[web.1]: 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705817+00:00 app[web.1]: 'User-Agent': 'axios/0.16.2',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705819+00:00 app[web.1]: 'Content-Length': 54 },
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705820+00:00 app[web.1]: method: 'post',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705829+00:00 app[web.1]: url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/me/message_creatives?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705831+00:00 app[web.1]: data: '{"message":[{"text":"Today\'s information is HERE!"}]}' },
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705832+00:00 app[web.1]: request:
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705834+00:00 app[web.1]: ClientRequest {
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705835+00:00 app[web.1]: domain: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705837+00:00 app[web.1]: _events:
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705839+00:00 app[web.1]: { socket: [Function],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705840+00:00 app[web.1]: abort: [Function],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705842+00:00 app[web.1]: aborted: [Function],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705844+00:00 app[web.1]: error: [Function],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705845+00:00 app[web.1]: timeout: [Function],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705847+00:00 app[web.1]: prefinish: [Function: requestOnPrefinish] },
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705848+00:00 app[web.1]: _eventsCount: 6,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705850+00:00 app[web.1]: _maxListeners: undefined,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705852+00:00 app[web.1]: output: [],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705853+00:00 app[web.1]: outputEncodings: [],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705855+00:00 app[web.1]: outputCallbacks: [],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705856+00:00 app[web.1]: outputSize: 0,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705858+00:00 app[web.1]: writable: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705860+00:00 app[web.1]: _last: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705861+00:00 app[web.1]: upgrading: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705863+00:00 app[web.1]: chunkedEncoding: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705865+00:00 app[web.1]: shouldKeepAlive: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705867+00:00 app[web.1]: useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705868+00:00 app[web.1]: sendDate: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705870+00:00 app[web.1]: _removedConnection: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705871+00:00 app[web.1]: _removedContLen: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705873+00:00 app[web.1]: _removedTE: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705875+00:00 app[web.1]: _contentLength: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705876+00:00 app[web.1]: _hasBody: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705878+00:00 app[web.1]: _trailer: '',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705880+00:00 app[web.1]: finished: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705881+00:00 app[web.1]: _headerSent: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705883+00:00 app[web.1]: socket:
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705885+00:00 app[web.1]: TLSSocket {
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705887+00:00 app[web.1]: _tlsOptions: [Object],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705889+00:00 app[web.1]: _secureEstablished: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705890+00:00 app[web.1]: _securePending: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705892+00:00 app[web.1]: _newSessionPending: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705894+00:00 app[web.1]: _controlReleased: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705895+00:00 app[web.1]: _SNICallback: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705897+00:00 app[web.1]: servername: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705899+00:00 app[web.1]: npnProtocol: undefined,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705900+00:00 app[web.1]: alpnProtocol: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705902+00:00 app[web.1]: authorized: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705904+00:00 app[web.1]: authorizationError: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705906+00:00 app[web.1]: encrypted: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705907+00:00 app[web.1]: _events: [Object],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705908+00:00 app[web.1]: _eventsCount: 9,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705910+00:00 app[web.1]: connecting: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705911+00:00 app[web.1]: _hadError: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705913+00:00 app[web.1]: _handle: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705914+00:00 app[web.1]: _parent: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705916+00:00 app[web.1]: _host: 'graph.facebook.com',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705917+00:00 app[web.1]: _readableState: [ReadableState],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705919+00:00 app[web.1]: readable: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705921+00:00 app[web.1]: domain: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705922+00:00 app[web.1]: _maxListeners: undefined,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705924+00:00 app[web.1]: _writableState: [WritableState],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705926+00:00 app[web.1]: writable: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705927+00:00 app[web.1]: allowHalfOpen: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705929+00:00 app[web.1]: _bytesDispatched: 456,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705931+00:00 app[web.1]: _sockname: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705932+00:00 app[web.1]: _pendingData: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705934+00:00 app[web.1]: _pendingEncoding: '',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705936+00:00 app[web.1]: server: undefined,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705937+00:00 app[web.1]: _server: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705939+00:00 app[web.1]: ssl: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705940+00:00 app[web.1]: _requestCert: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705942+00:00 app[web.1]: _rejectUnauthorized: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705944+00:00 app[web.1]: parser: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705946+00:00 app[web.1]: _httpMessage: [Circular],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705947+00:00 app[web.1]: read: [Function],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705949+00:00 app[web.1]: _consuming: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705950+00:00 app[web.1]: _idleNext: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705952+00:00 app[web.1]: _idlePrev: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705953+00:00 app[web.1]: _idleTimeout: -1,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705955+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705957+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11622,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705958+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 842,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705960+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705961+00:00 app[web.1]: connection:
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705963+00:00 app[web.1]: TLSSocket {
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705964+00:00 app[web.1]: _tlsOptions: [Object],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705966+00:00 app[web.1]: _secureEstablished: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705968+00:00 app[web.1]: _securePending: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705970+00:00 app[web.1]: _newSessionPending: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705971+00:00 app[web.1]: _controlReleased: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705973+00:00 app[web.1]: _SNICallback: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705974+00:00 app[web.1]: servername: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705976+00:00 app[web.1]: npnProtocol: undefined,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705977+00:00 app[web.1]: alpnProtocol: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705979+00:00 app[web.1]: authorized: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705982+00:00 app[web.1]: authorizationError: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705984+00:00 app[web.1]: encrypted: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705985+00:00 app[web.1]: _events: [Object],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705987+00:00 app[web.1]: _eventsCount: 9,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705988+00:00 app[web.1]: connecting: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705990+00:00 app[web.1]: _hadError: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705992+00:00 app[web.1]: _handle: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705993+00:00 app[web.1]: _parent: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.705995+00:00 app[web.1]: _host: 'graph.facebook.com',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706004+00:00 app[web.1]: _readableState: [ReadableState],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706006+00:00 app[web.1]: readable: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706007+00:00 app[web.1]: domain: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706009+00:00 app[web.1]: _maxListeners: undefined,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706010+00:00 app[web.1]: _writableState: [WritableState],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706012+00:00 app[web.1]: writable: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706013+00:00 app[web.1]: allowHalfOpen: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706015+00:00 app[web.1]: _bytesDispatched: 456,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706017+00:00 app[web.1]: _sockname: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706019+00:00 app[web.1]: _pendingData: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706020+00:00 app[web.1]: _pendingEncoding: '',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706022+00:00 app[web.1]: server: undefined,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706023+00:00 app[web.1]: _server: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706025+00:00 app[web.1]: ssl: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706027+00:00 app[web.1]: _requestCert: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706028+00:00 app[web.1]: _rejectUnauthorized: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706030+00:00 app[web.1]: parser: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706032+00:00 app[web.1]: _httpMessage: [Circular],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706033+00:00 app[web.1]: read: [Function],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706035+00:00 app[web.1]: _consuming: true,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706036+00:00 app[web.1]: _idleNext: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706038+00:00 app[web.1]: _idlePrev: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706040+00:00 app[web.1]: _idleTimeout: -1,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706041+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(res)]: [TLSWrap],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706043+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(asyncId)]: 11622,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706045+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 842,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706047+00:00 app[web.1]: [Symbol(connect-options)]: [Object] },
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706050+00:00 app[web.1]: _header: 'POST /v2.11/me/message_creatives?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN> HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\nUser-Agent: axios/0.16.2\r\nContent-Length: 54\r\nHost: graph.facebook.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706052+00:00 app[web.1]: _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706054+00:00 app[web.1]: agent:
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706056+00:00 app[web.1]: Agent {
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706057+00:00 app[web.1]: domain: null,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706059+00:00 app[web.1]: _events: [Object],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706061+00:00 app[web.1]: _eventsCount: 1,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706062+00:00 app[web.1]: _maxListeners: undefined,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706064+00:00 app[web.1]: defaultPort: 443,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706066+00:00 app[web.1]: protocol: 'https:',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706068+00:00 app[web.1]: options: [Object],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706069+00:00 app[web.1]: requests: {},
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706071+00:00 app[web.1]: sockets: [Object],
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706072+00:00 app[web.1]: freeSockets: {},
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706074+00:00 app[web.1]: keepAliveMsecs: 1000,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706076+00:00 app[web.1]: keepAlive: false,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706077+00:00 app[web.1]: maxSockets: Infinity,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706079+00:00 app[web.1]: maxFreeSockets: 256,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706081+00:00 app[web.1]: maxCachedSessions: 100,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706083+00:00 app[web.1]: _sessionCache: [Object] },
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706085+00:00 app[web.1]: socketPath: undefined,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706086+00:00 app[web.1]: timeout: undefined,
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706088+00:00 app[web.1]: method: 'POST',
2018-08-10T00:12:25.706093+00:00 app[web.1]: path: '/v2.11/me/message_creatives?access_token=<ACCESS_TOKEN>
```

Note: The places where it says **ACCESS_TOKEN** was deliberately edited by me before posting, for security reasons, so that part is working fine.

MY code that does the work is this:

```
const templates = require('./templates')
const dialogsContent = require('../dialogs-content').dialogsContent
const axios = require('axios')

class broadcastSender {

  static formatMessage (message) {
    return templates.format(message)
  }

  static async getCreativeId (message) {
    // -- The format of the message from the dialog is in a generic format
    // -- We need to format it to the Facebook format
    const formattedMessage = this.formatMessage(message)
    // -- Execute the first step to send a single Broadcast Message
    // -- Get that message's ID from Facebook
    await axios.request({
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      url: `${process.env.FB_BASE_URL}/${process.env.FB_VERSION}/me/message_creatives?access_token=${process.env.FB_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
      method: 'post',
      data: formattedMessage,
    })
      .then(data => {
        return data.message_creative_id
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }

  static async prepareCreativeIdsArray (dialogName) {
    // -- The Dialog is an array of messages
    // -- We get the Dialog and assign it to a messages array
    const messagesArray = dialogsContent.messages[dialogName]
    const IdsArray = []
    // -- Fill the array with the Ids of the BroadCast Messages
    for (const message of messagesArray) {
      const messageIdFromFacebook = await this.getCreativeId(message)
      if (!isNaN(parseInt(messageIdFromFacebook, 10))) {
        IdsArray.push(messageIdFromFacebook)
      }
    }
    return IdsArray
  }

  static async getCustomLabelId (label) {
    const labelsIdsArray = (await axios.get(`${process.env.FB_BASE_URL}/${process.env.FB_VERSION}/me/custom_labels?fields=name&access_token=${process.env.FB_ACCESS_TOKEN}`)).data.data
    for (const labelData of labelsIdsArray) {
      if (labelData.name === label) {
        return labelData.id
      }
    }
  }

  static async sendBroadcastMessage (dialogName, labelToExclude) {
    const IdsArray = await this.prepareCreativeIdsArray(dialogName)
    const customLabelId = await this.getCustomLabelId(labelToExclude)
    console.log('IDS ARRAY %s\n labelid %s', IdsArray, customLabelId)
    for (const broadcastId of IdsArray) {

      const creativeData = Object.assign({},
        {
          message_creative_id: broadcastId,
          notification_type: 'REGULAR',
          targeting: { labels: { operator: 'NOT', values: [{ customLabelId }] } },
        })
      // -- Send the message to facebook
      await axios.request({
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        url: `${process.env.FB_BASE_URL}/${process.env.FB_VERSION}/me/broadcast_messages?access_token=${process.env.FB_ACCESS_TOKEN}`,
        method: 'post',
        data: JSON.stringify(creativeData),
      })
        .then(data => {
          return data.broadcast_id
        })
        .catch(error => {
          throw error
        })
    }
  }

}

module.exports = broadcastSender
```

**The code for the templates.format function is this**

```
  module.exports = class templates {
  static format (genericMessage) {

    let type = genericMessage.type
    const payload = genericMessage.content
    let fallback_text = ''

    const isPersonalized = /{{first_name}}/i

    if (isPersonalized.test(JSON.stringify(payload))) {
      type = 'dynamic_text'
      fallback_text = payload.replace(isPersonalized, 'buddy')
    }
    let preparedMessage

    if (type === 'carousel') {

      const carousel = []
      // NOTE: content_type supported by FB are text, location, phone number and email
      for (const cards of payload) {
        if (cards.buttons && cards.subtitle) {

          const buttonsOfCard = []
          for (const buttonTemplate of cards.buttons) {

            if (buttonTemplate.type === 'postback') {
              buttonsOfCard.push({
                type: buttonTemplate.type,
                title: buttonTemplate.title,
                payload: buttonTemplate.value,
              })
            } else if (buttonTemplate.type === 'web_url') {
              buttonsOfCard.push({
                type: buttonTemplate.type,
                title: buttonTemplate.title,
                url: buttonTemplate.url,
              })
            } else if (buttonTemplate.type === 'element_share') {
              buttonsOfCard.push({
                type: buttonTemplate.type,
              })
            }

          }
          carousel.push({
            title: cards.title,
            image_url: cards.imageUrl,
            subtitle: cards.subtitle,
            buttons: buttonsOfCard,
          })

        } else if (cards.buttons) {

          const buttonsOfCard = []
          for (const buttonTemplate of cards.buttons) {

            if (buttonTemplate.type === 'postback') {
              buttonsOfCard.push({
                type: buttonTemplate.type,
                title: buttonTemplate.title,
                payload: buttonTemplate.value,
              })

            } else if (buttonTemplate.type === 'web_url') {
              buttonsOfCard.push({
                type: buttonTemplate.type,
                title: buttonTemplate.title,
                url: buttonTemplate.url,
              })

            } else if (buttonTemplate.type === 'element_share') {
              buttonsOfCard.push({
                type: buttonTemplate.type,
              })
            }

          }
          carousel.push({
            title: cards.title,
            image_url: cards.imageUrl,
            buttons: buttonsOfCard,
          })

        } else if (cards.subtitle) {

          carousel.push({
            title: cards.title,
            image_url: cards.imageUrl,
            subtitle: cards.subtitle,
          })

        } else {

          carousel.push({
            title: cards.title,
            image_url: cards.imageUrl,
          })

        }
      }

      // Set the prepared message
      preparedMessage = JSON.stringify({
        message: [{
          attachment: {
            type: 'template',
            payload: {
              template_type: 'generic',
              elements: carousel,
            },
          },
        }],
      })

    }

    if (type === 'card') {
      const elements = payload[0]
      if (elements.buttons && elements.subtitle) {

        const buttonsOfCard = []
        for (const buttonTemplate of elements.buttons) {

          if (buttonTemplate.type === 'postback') {
            buttonsOfCard.push({
              type: buttonTemplate.type,
              title: buttonTemplate.title,
              payload: buttonTemplate.value,
            })
          } else if (buttonTemplate.type === 'web_url') {
            buttonsOfCard.push({
              type: buttonTemplate.type,
              title: buttonTemplate.title,
              url: buttonTemplate.url,
            })
          } else if (buttonTemplate.type === 'element_share') {
            buttonsOfCard.push({
              type: buttonTemplate.type,
            })
          }

        }
        payload[0] = ({
          title: elements.title,
          image_url: elements.imageUrl,
          subtitle: elements.subtitle,
          buttons: buttonsOfCard,
        })

      } else if (elements.buttons) {

        const buttonsOfCard = []
        for (const buttonTemplate of elements.buttons) {

          if (buttonTemplate.type === 'postback') {
            buttonsOfCard.push({
              type: buttonTemplate.type,
              title: buttonTemplate.title,
              payload: buttonTemplate.value,
            })

          } else if (buttonTemplate.type === 'web_url') {
            buttonsOfCard.push({
              type: buttonTemplate.type,
              title: buttonTemplate.title,
              url: buttonTemplate.url,
            })

          } else if (buttonTemplate.type === 'element_share') {
            buttonsOfCard.push({
              type: buttonTemplate.type,
            })
          }

        }
        payload[0] = ({
          title: elements.title,
          image_url: elements.imageUrl,
          buttons: buttonsOfCard,
        })

      } else if (elements.subtitle) {

        payload[0] = ({
          title: elements.title,
          image_url: elements.imageUrl,
          subtitle: elements.subtitle,
        })

      } else {

        payload[0] = ({
          title: elements.title,
          image_url: elements.imageUrl,
        })

      }

      // Set the prepared message
      preparedMessage = JSON.stringify({
        message: [{
          attachment: {
            type: 'template',
            payload: {
              template_type: 'generic',
              elements: payload,
            },
          },
        }],
      })
    }

    if (type === 'button') {

      const buttonsArray = []
      for (const buttons of payload.buttons) {

        if (buttons.type === 'postback') {
          buttonsArray.push({
            type: buttons.type,
            title: buttons.title,
            payload: buttons.value,
          })
        } else if (buttons.type === 'web_url') {
          buttonsArray.push({
            type: buttons.type,
            title: buttons.title,
            url: buttons.url,
          })
        } else if (buttons.type === 'element_share') {
          buttonsArray.push({
            type: buttons.type,
          })
        }

      }

      // Set the prepared message
      preparedMessage = JSON.stringify({
        message: [{
          attachment: {
            type: 'template',
            payload: {
              template_type: type,
              text: payload.title,
              buttons: buttonsArray,
            },
          },
        }],
      })

    } else if (type === 'quickReplies') {
      const quickRepliesArray = []
      // NOTE: content_type supported by FB are text, location, phone number 
and email
      for (const buttons of payload.buttons) {
        if (buttons.image_url) {
          quickRepliesArray.push({
            content_type: 'text',
            title: buttons.title,
            payload: buttons.value,
            image_url: buttons.image_url,
          })
        } else {
          quickRepliesArray.push({
            content_type: 'text',
            title: buttons.title,
            payload: buttons.value,
          })
        }
      }

      // Set the prepared Message
      preparedMessage = JSON.stringify({
        message: [{
          text: payload.title,
          quick_replies: quickRepliesArray,
        }],
      })
    } else if (type === 'text') {
      preparedMessage = JSON.stringify({
        message: [{ text: payload }],
      })
    } else if (type === 'dynamic_text') {
      preparedMessage = JSON.stringify({
        messages: [{
          dynamic_text: {
            text: payload,
            fallback_text,
          },
        }],
      })
    } else if (type === 'audio') {
      preparedMessage = JSON.stringify({
        message: [{
          attachment: {
            type,
            payload: {
              url: payload,
              is_reusable: true,
            },
          },
        }],
      })
    } else if (type === 'video') {
      preparedMessage = JSON.stringify({
        message: [{
          attachment: {
            type,
            payload: {
              url: payload,
              is_reusable: true,
            },
          },
        }],
      })
    } else if (type === 'image') {
      preparedMessage = JSON.stringify({
        message: [{
          attachment: {
            type,
            payload: {
              url: payload,
              is_reusable: true,
            },
          },
        }],
      })
    } else if (type === 'file') {
      preparedMessage = JSON.stringify({
        message: [{
          attachment: {
            type,
            payload: {
              url: payload,
              is_reusable: true,
            },
          },
        }],
      })
    }
    return preparedMessage
  }

}
```

*Behavior wanted*
This first step of the process of sending a broadcast message to messenger is supposed to return an object with a "message_creative_id" property.

Comment: _“The places where it says ACCESS_TOKEN was deliberately edited by me before posting, for security reasons”_ - you missed one, which means you should first of all go invalidate that token now (f.e. by changing the account password of the user who granted it)

Comment: @Cbroe thanks, I just noticed. I already invalidated that token.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, it was a missing "s" at the end of "message".
Facebook has a similar looking format for sending replies to users, so the issue came when using that format for the broadcast messages which instead of "message" has a property called "messages".